# I created a profile page that i would like users to see but not be able to edit

Tags: view, profile

Hi I have created a profile form page, where users add their details, the details are entered into a database, I would like other users to see (they click on a link) the profile page but it can not be edited it. How do I create this? Is there a tutorial available that i could follow?
I have a hunch that you have to create a new php page and php echo the form somehow?
`<?php echo $form; ?>`

thank you
Melanie

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the database, you could just echo out the data stored there for each user. since the form is there to store the data for users who own the page...users who do not should just see the info which will be pulled down from the database.

Comment: thank you - sorry just realised where i have to go to see answers to my questions!

Comment: its ok...most likely the easiest way to do this would be to have the profile form accesible from however you have the people's account page set up and then have a seperate page that is displayed using php to echo out the data in the database, so two different pages with two different links. one for the owner to edit, the other page to display the data to all other users.